# Django - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'alluth'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I encountered an error while trying to make migration. I reinstalled the app yet i still saw the same error.

Here is my setting file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # 3rd Party
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'alluth.socialaccount',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',

    # Local
    'posts.apps.PostsConfig',
]

# Peculiar to django-allauth app
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

SITE_ID = 1
```

This is the error am getting when i run  `python manage.py migrate`:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'alluth'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in 3rd party section of INSTALLED APPS.

`'alluth.socialaccount'`

it is a typo, it should be

`'allauth.socialaccount',`, pay attention to alluth -> allauth